# Front end post submissions do not get submitted in the category

Tags: php, categories, front-end, wp-insert-post

If I submit the post after choosing a category the post doesnt get submitted and instead it takes me to the category page i have selected.However if i delete the fieldset "category" and fill the form it works fine. Any solution to this?

The PHP is this.

```
<?php
if( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] ) &&  $_POST['action'] == "new_post") {


if (isset ($_POST['description'])) {
    $description = $_POST['description'];
} else {
    echo 'Please enter some notes';
}

$tags = $_POST['post_tags'];

$category = array(intval($_POST['cat']));

// ADD THE FORM INPUT TO $new_post ARRAY
$new_post = array(
'post_title'    =>   $title,
'post_content'  =>   $description,
 'post_category' => $category,   
'tags_input'    =>   array($tags),
'post_status'   =>   'publish',           
'post_type' =>   'post',  //

);


$pid = wp_insert_post($new_post);


wp_set_post_tags($pid, $_POST['post_tags']);
wp_set_post_categories($pid, $_POST['cat'] );

$link = get_permalink( $pid );
wp_redirect( $link );
}



do_action('wp_insert_post', 'wp_insert_post');

?>
```

And the html..

```
 <div class="wpcf7" style="margin-top: 100px;">
 <form id="new_post" name="new_post" method="post" action="" class="wpcf7-form"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <!-- post name -->
  <fieldset name="name">
      <label for="title">Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="title" value="" tabindex="5" name="title" />
        </fieldset>

        <!-- post Category -->
 <fieldset class="category">
    <label for="cat">Type:</label>
</fieldset>

        <!-- post Content -->
        <fieldset class="content">
            <label for="description">Description and Notes:</label>
            <textarea id="description" tabindex="15" name="description" cols="80" rows="10"></textarea>
        </fieldset>




        <!-- post tags -->
        <fieldset class="tags">
            <label for="post_tags">Additional Keywords (comma separated):</label>
            <input type="text" value="" tabindex="35" name="post_tags" id="post_tags" />
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset class="submit">
            <input type="submit" value="Post Review" tabindex="40" id="submit" name="submit" />
        </fieldset>

        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="new_post" />
        <?php wp_nonce_field( 'new-post' ); ?>
    </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

an echo before inserting content, are you sure ?

Possibly sending headers, blocks insert POST request and set pid to empty value.

```
if (isset ($_POST['description'])) {
     $description = $_POST['description'];
} else {
    echo 'Please enter some notes';
}
```

Comment: i was gonna get to validation after the category issue was over...